# when I run this command "firebase emulators: start" it does not run my localhost

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express

**it shows such a message in my console when I run my express**

```
$ firebase emulators:start
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, database, hosting
!  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, firestore, pubsub, storage
+  functions: Using node@16 from host.
i  database: Database Emulator logging to database-debug.log
!  database: Fatal error occurred: 
   Database Emulator has exited because java is not installed, you can install it from https://openjdk.java.net/install/,
   stopping all running emulators
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  database: Stopping Database Emulator
!  database: Error stopping Database Emulator
i  hub: Stopping emulator hu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noticed the error message in your output?

```
Database Emulator has exited because java is not installed,
you can install it from https://openjdk.java.net/install/
```

I would recommend following the instructions to install java.
Also check the requirements here https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure